# Two ways to calculate dissolved oxygen

Tags: solubility

To calculate the dissolved oxygen in water at saturation pressure at 25 °C, we do:

$$
D_\ce{O2} = K_\mathrm{H} \times M \times p_\mathrm{g}
$$

$$
D_\ce{O2}~[\pu{g/L}]= 1.26\times10^{-3}~[\pu{mol/L/atm}] \times 32~[\pu{g/mol}] \times 0.21~[\pu{atm}]
$$

I used $\pu{1.26E-3 mol/L/atm}$ for the Henry's constant for $\ce{O2}$ in water at 25C which is from Warneck and Williams (2012), which was in turn taken from Battino (1981). This returns a dissolved oxygen of $\pu{8.47 mg/L}$.

Benson (1980) reports dissolved oxygen for "a body of pure water is in thermodynamic equilibrium with an atmosphere of standard composition saturated with water vapor at a total pressure $P$" as 8.26 mg/L which is a difference of 2.5 %. The Benson paper suggests an error of around 0.02 %. Why is there a difference in these two methods? Is it due to different assumptions being made? Or perhaps rounding errors in how data is presented?

Comment: To me, 8.26 vs 8.47 is no difference at all, and bold claims about 0.02% should be taken _cum grano salis_.

Comment: The 21% figure is for dry air. Benson assumes air is saturated with water vapor.

Comment: In either case it is a case of the grain of salt when the numbers used have a 1e-3 resolution and the precision is reported as "around" 2e-4. I'd call BS right then and there (unless OP has truncated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 21.0% of oxygen by volume in air is from dry air. Data for [dry air from webpage](http://eesc.columbia.edu/courses/ees/slides/climate/table_1.html) of Columbia University's Department of Earth and Environmental Sciences.

Note that the "% by volume"/100 for dry air also corresponds to the partial pressure in atmospheres. For air saturated with water at 25 C, [the vapor pressure of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water), according to Wikipedia, is 0.0313 atm. The second column is calculated by multiplying all dry air values by (1-0.0313)=0.9687.

$$\newcommand{\d}[2]{#1.&\hspace{-1em}#2}
\begin{array}{lrl}
\hline
\text{Gas} &\hspace{-5em}\text{dry air}&\ce{H2O}\text{ sat. air} \\
 & \text{% by volume} & \text{% by volume} \\
\hline
\ce{N2} &  78.084    & 75.640 \\
\ce{O2}  & 20.947    & 20.291 \\
\ce{H2O} & 0.0      &  3.13 \\
\ce{Ar}  &  0.934    &  0.905 \\
\ce{CO2} & 0.035    &  0.034 \\
\ce{Ne}  &  0.001818 &  0.001761 \\
\ce{He}  &  0.000524 & 0.000508 \\
\ce{CH4} &  0.00017  &  0.00016 \\
\ce{Kr}  &  0.000114 &  0.000110 \\
\ce{H2}  &  0.000053 & 0.000053 \\
\ce{N2O} & 0.000031 &  0.000030 \\
\ce{Xe}  &  0.0000087&  0.0000084 \\
\hline
\text{TOTAL}& 100.0027187 & 100.0026304 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now correcting the data from Warneck and Williams (evidently Warneck,  P.  and  Williams,  J.:  The  Atmospheric  Chemist’s  Companion:  Numerical  Data  for  Use  in  the  Atmospheric  Sciences, Springer Verlag, 2012) for the value of water saturated air

$\ce{O2} = \dfrac{20.291}{21}\times 8.47 = 8.18$ mg/L

This is much better agreement with the [Benson (1980)](https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4319/lo.1980.25.4.0662) data.

The OP's value of 1.26e-3 Mol/L/atm for the Henry's constant for O2 in water at 25C was evidently take from Table 8.23 of Warneck and Williams. The value also has a list error bracket of +/- 0.02.

$$\dfrac{0.02}{1.26}\times 100\text{%} = 1.6 \text{ %}$$

For the two dissolved oxygen values:

$$\dfrac{8.26-8.18}{8.26}\times100\text{ %} = -0.97 \text{ %}$$

so the values are within the error limits for Henry's constant.